# How to get telegram messages without any delay from any server using the API or is there a get request that I can use?

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram

I want to get all the messages from the telegram servers I'm in and want to display the messages in the terminal.
I used the telethon python library but the delay is too much takes like 2 to 3 seconds to fetch the message after it has already appeared in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found is to use the pyrogram library, it displays messages faster than the Telegram App itself which is what I wanted.